# How can I determine the algorithm used for hashing passwords in a Grails app using springsecurity?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have never used Grails (or Java for that matter). I am rebuilding an app, originally built with Grails, from the ground up using another language/framework. I would like to bring over existing users from the production DB. I have full access to the DB and password hashes. I also have access to the entire Grails source.

I have been able to figure out that the springsecurity plugin appears to be used. I have done simple searches in the project for keywords like SHA1, MD5, and bcrypt with no results. I have also searched the source for "grails.plugins.springsecurity.password.algorithm" and it does not appear.

Is there a common encryption used by springsecurity?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I still don't know how to actually determine this. I realized that my hash was 64 characters, Googled that to see it was likely SHA-256. I used an online javascript hash tool to hash my password and compared the results. I verified it was SHA-256.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Spring Security Core plugin documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual.1273/guide/12%20Password%20and%20Account%20Protection.html#12.1%20Password%20Encryption), the default encryption is SHA-256.

That means it does something like this:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest

...

String password = "<password to be encrypted>";
MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
byte[] hash = digest.digest(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Comment: I did eventually figure this out by chance. I just did a search across the project and could not find "SHA-256", "256", etc, so I guess it is just using the straight-up default. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

search for documents containing

```
  "springSecurityService.encodePassword("
```

or

```
 "getEncodedPassword("
```

or

```
  ".encodeAsURLSafeBase64("
```

and in you "/domains/" directory sure is some file like

```
user.groovy
```

wich could bring some light into context and maybe contains some helpfull methods
in your "/controllers/" dir you could search for the controller that handles the registration, maybe it has a dependy for a service wich iss doing that /services/

Comment: sorry, but what does `HashCodeBuilder` and `@EqualsAndHashCode` have to do with password encrypting?